# How to make sure Istio side car container not override the application response headers

Tags: proxy, devops, istio, sidecar

Istio sidecar container is overriding the response headers which are being sent by application. How can we avoid it?

Comment: Response headers can be changed either using virtualservice or through envoy filters.  Please check if those are being set.

Comment: Has your issue been resolved?If yes, can you post the procedure you've followed as Solution and accept it?